# How to compute such a limit with euler?

Tags: real-analysis

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{e^x - 1}$

Can somebody show me step to step how do this function is going to infinity from both sides ?

As for me i see that $e^x$ is going to $1$ but i think that from the beginning i'm making mistakes.

Comment: It's a limit, not a limitation...

Comment: my bad , sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x<0$. Then $e^x<1$ and $\frac1{e^x-1}<0$. The closer $x$ gets to $0$ while still being negative, the closer $e^x-1$ gets to $0$ while still being negative. Thus $\frac1{e^x-1}$ approaches $-\infty$ when $x$ approaches $0$ from the left.

Suppose $x>0$. Then $e^x-1>0$. Notice that we have the bound $x<e^x-1$ for all $x\ne 0$. Thus $\frac1{e^x-1}$ is sandwiched between $x=0$ and $y=1/x$ for $x>0$, meaning it approaches $+\infty$ when $x$ approaches $0$ from the right.

Answer (score 0):

As $x \to 0, e^x \to 1,$ so $e^x-1 \to 0$ and the fraction goes to infinity.  If you use the Taylor series $e^x \approx 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots,$ so $e^x -1 \approx x$ and your fraction becomes $\frac 1x$ with the same conclusion.

Comment: As the OP mentions "from both sides" it is worth discussing the behavior when approaching $0$ from the left and how it varies from the behavior when approaching $0$ from the right and how to describe the result in the event that "diverging to infinity" is treated as a different outcome than "diverging to negative infinity."